# Laravel link to action not working without a defined route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, controller, routes

I might be misunderstanding the link to route helper, but its not working without a route set up in my routes file.

```
{{ link_to_action('UserController@loginWithFacebook', 'Facebook Login in', $parameters = array(), $attributes = array('class' => 'btn btn-primary fb-login-btn')); }}
```

Then an old route when I was linking to a URI was:

```
    Route::get('loginuser2', array('uses' => 'UserController@loginWithFacebook'));
```

However, I thought link_to_action was a direct call to the method. After removing the above link in my routes file I get not defined route errors for the controller method.

Any ideas how to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant link to an action if the route itself does not exist. The route must be defined.

So you need to keep the route defined, and then `link_to_action()` will continue to work. On the backend it is looking at your routes to find the same route with that action - and uses that URL.

There is no way to avoid it.

Comment: Okay I see, I was under the impression link to action was a direct call to the method. I don't use that URL but shall have to keep it defined for Laravel's sake. Thanks.

Comment: It is defined as a call to the method - but think about how will a web browser know how to hit that method without a url. The url is what is defined in the routes file - so it kinda works in reverse.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense now someone has said it ^.^

Answer (score -1):

link_to_action is used to link to a controller. you should use

link_to to generate html link

echo link_to('foo/bar', $title, $attributes = array(), $secure = null);